# Getting error when trying to set value/key pairs with SBJsonWriter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, sbjson

Getting the following error when trying to set value/key pairs:

```
2011-06-21 16:21:16.727 agent[94408:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SBJsonWriter 0xab31230> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key key.'
```

Here is the code:

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];

[writer setValue:@"val" forKey:@"key"];

NSString *json = [writer JSONRepresentation];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"json: @%", json]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is using the key-value coding from the `(NSObject)` category,

to use the dictionary interface: 
import JSON.h then:

```
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict setValue:@"val" forKey:@"key"];

    NSLog(@"json: %@", [dict JSONRepresentation]);
```

p.s. NSLog accepts a format, so you don't need to make a string from a format to pass to it.

Comment: Ah sweet - so I don't even need to use the JSON libraries then? Can just do it all with NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: they are implemented as categories on existing classes, so not directly.

Comment: Correction... what I meant is that I can use NSMutableDictionary for writing a json string from scratch, or use the SBJsonParser for parsing it into an NSDictionary object.

Comment: @xil3 - no. SBJson creates a category on NSDictionary (inherited by NSMutableDictionary) for you, but you still need to link to the library and include the header file to get that behaviour.